# Usar onmouseover para trocar a cor das divs criadas com createElement

Tags: javascript

o objetivo desse código é q sempre q o usuário clique no botão, apareça na tela, uma div na forma de um quadrado, e ao passar o mouse em cima de um dos quadrados criados, sua background-color seja alterada para uma cor aleatória. Porém, não estou conseguindo mudar a cor dos quadrados.
HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <button id="btn">Criar quadrado</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Código para criar as divs quadradas:

```
    btnElement = document.querySelector('button#btn');

    btnElement.onclick = function () {
        var quadradoElement = document.createElement('div');
        quadradoElement.setAttribute('class', 'box')
        quadradoElement.style.width = '100px';
        quadradoElement.style.height = '100px';
        quadradoElement.style.backgroundColor = '#060621';

        var divElement = document.querySelector('div#app');
        divElement.appendChild(quadradoElement);
    }
```

Função para gerar cor aleatória:

```
function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        var color = "#";
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }

    var newColor = getRandomColor();
```

Código q não está funcionando, seria para mudar a cor das divs ao sobrepor o mouse:

```
var quadradoCriado=document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        quadradoCriado.onmouseover= function(){
            quadradoCriado.style.backgroundColor=newColor;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/omd9kpw4/1/

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta para sincronizar o código que está no fiddle com o que está na pergunta. Algumas partes que estão lá estão faltando aqui... [Leia este guia para saber mais.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5489#5489)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do Button, adiciona o evento de click dessa forma "onclick="criarDiv();".

```
<script>


     function criarDiv() { 
        var quadradoElement = document.createElement('div');
        quadradoElement.setAttribute('class', 'box')
        quadradoElement.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'trocarCorFundoDiv(this);')//Adicionar o evento do mouse passando a div que esta sendo criado.
        quadradoElement.style.width = '100px';
        quadradoElement.style.height = '100px';
        quadradoElement.style.backgroundColor = '#1ccdda';

        var divElement = document.getElementById("app");
        divElement.appendChild(quadradoElement);


        }
    function trocarCorFundoDiv(quadradoCriado){  
         quadradoCriado.style.backgroundColor  = getRandomColor();//mudar a cor de fundo da div passada por parametro
    }


    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        var color = "#";
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }  
        return color;
    }

</script>
```